# According to MVVM pattern — who's responsible?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

According to MVVM there should be no logic inside the models. Let's assume there's a Person model which contains two properties:

```
public class Person {
    public string Costcenter { get; private set; }
    public User User { get; private set; }
}
```

The User object itself contains an other person object which among other properties contains a property "Costcenter".

```
public class User {
    public OtherPerson Person {get; private set; }
}

public class OtherPerson {
    public string Costcenter {get; private set; }
}
```

> **OtherPerson** is a totally different class than **Person**

Now my actual question: Who would be responsible for checking if the Costcenter in Person equals the Costcenter in OtherPerson?

```
Person.Costcenter == Person.User.OtherPerson.Costcenter
```

There aren't much possibilities:

1. The ViewModel is responsible
2. Small pieces of code could be implemented inside the Model
3. A check could be implemented as a getter property

---

```
public ViewModel(){
    [...]
    public bool IsCostcenterEqual(Person p){
        return p.Costcenter == p.User.OtherPerson.Costcenter;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Person {
    public string Costcenter { get; private set; }
    public User User { get; private set; }
    public bool CostcenterEquals(){
        return this.Costcenter == this.User.OtherPerson.Costcenter;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Person {
    public string Costcenter { get; private set; }
    public User User { get; private set; }
    public bool IsCostcenterEqualProperty{
        get{
            return this.Costcenter == this.User.OtherPerson.Costcenter;
        }
    }
}
```

At this point I'm not sure if this is just a matter of opinion but I'm looking for the best* way of solving this issue

> *) best = best fitting related to MVVM pattern

**Edit 1**

I forgot to mention that I'd like to use my Models for EF (if this matters)

Comment: "According to MVVM there should be no logic inside the models". Who told you so? I'd say there should be all the business logic.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that the Model should contain no logic? The entire business logic layer lives within the Model.

Comment: Ahhh MVVM. I think there are 7 different opinions on what MVVM is. Some people think DTOs are Models (I dont), Some people think the ViewModel is also the Model (well that would be VVM). See this sensible discussion on MVVM https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/MVVM-Best-Practices

Comment: @Clemens Shouldn't the models be POCO to make them easily serializable etc.?

Comment: @UweKeim IMO DTOs/Records that get serialized are not models. They are part of the persistence of service layer, not the presentation layer. Models define behaviour not structure. #dogma #justGetTheJobDone

Comment: @DavidArno : The anemic model design pattern, one of the most popular among architects says so. You may choose not to follow it but it definitely answers your question.

Comment: @LeeCampbell : These are business models (or business objects). The models as in the first M of MVVM are not necessarily those.

Comment: @AndreiRînea, I'm a big fan of the [Abstracted Domain Model](http://www.davidarno.org/2016/02/24/the-rotten-domain-model-is-dead-long-live-the-abstracted-domain-model/) (as I prefer to call it). However, just because the data objects passing in and out of the Model can be POCOs, doesn't mean the whole Model must be "anaemic" (IMO ;))

Comment: @LeeCampbell, "I think there are 7 different opinions on what MVVM" ... judging by the up/down votes on the answers and the varying opinions in the comments, you are spot on. Think this question sadly has to be closed as too opinion-based.

Comment: @AndreiRînea I hear you. Overloading terms like model (and service) really holds back our industry. If a Model is just a DTO then why isn't is called that? #lament. For small applications having your DTOs come straight of the wire/DB and on to the UI may be fine, but I find you fall of the cliff eventually in a mildly sophisticated Application.

Comment: A model is exactly that - a MODEL. If your business domain has the ability to place an order, then a MODEL of that DOMAIN should have a software implementation of the ability to place an order. If you're implementing your Domain Model in an Object Oriented Programming style, then you may find you end up with `Order.PlaceOrder()`. A DTO can't be a model because a DTO has no behaviour, and there are no business domains that have no behaviour.

Comment: @Clemens I'm pretty sure I learned it that way - the model should be a model by containing the properties - there should not be any logic in there. Apart from this I'm willing to learn new things - and if it fits my needs the best I totally agree that the model CAN and SHOULD contain the business logic. Even if this is more a fact of opinion I think this little "discussion" helps a lot.

Comment: Do you serve the pattern, or does the pattern serve you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the other answers and comments show, this is a topic that invokes a lot of passion and opinion. There's no one "right" way to do it.

You could take the position that the Model is just a set of DTOs/POCOs, or whatever you want to call them. Then your persistence and business logic layers live inside the ViewModel.

You could take the position that the Model is a persistence layer, responsible for persisting DTOs only and that the business logic lives in the ViewModel.

You could take the position that the ViewModel is only responsible for handling View logic (app behaviour) and that business logic and persistence exist in the Model.

You could take the position that... and so on. You might adopt an anaemic data model approach; or a rich data model approach, etc.

There is no one correct way to handle this. There are lost of equally valid ways. The two key points for all approached are:

1. Decide on an approach and stick to it. Be consistent throughout the solution.
2. Ensure the layers are properly decoupled, regardless of the approach taken.

Comment: Okay, I see - this is not a black and white thing. Because this is mora an opinion based discussion as mentioned couple of times I think your answer fits best :) Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but this is non-sense. There is nothing about passion and opinions, just about applying patterns for better maintainable code. While the OP didn't clearly define the word of "Model" in his case. ViewModels in MVVM always do only presentation logic (handling user input, calling domain services/business layer). If one ever puts persistence and business layer in the ViewModel s/he is clearly doing it wrong, as this violates the first SOLID principle: Single responsibility principle: An object should just have one responsibility

Comment: @Tseng, you are entitled to your opinion...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)#Overview ;)

Comment: @Tseng, You are confusing responsibilities of classes with responsibilities of components of a pattern. By your logic, if I put both the persistence and business layers in the Model, I'm violating SOLID. Clearly if I have a *class* that does both, it's a violation, but a well designed system will have a many-to-one relationship between classes and components of a pattern. So the idea that the persistence and business layers mustn't be in the ViewModel component is purely opinion. It's opinion I agree with, but it's still opinion.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have more classes here than you think. Your ViewModel classes are doing a similar job to controllers in MVC. They shouldn't have any of your business's logic in them, but they should coordinate the classes that do, which is your application logic.

So we have "Application Logic" which is controlling the UI, binding data to the view, and performing the integration between what the user does/sees and the "Business Logic" that implements the rules and invariants around it.

If they didn't have any logic at all, they'd be Data Transfer Objects, and of little use (DTOs are literally just for moving data around in a known "shape").

Business logic will typically be in either "Transaction Scripts" (often we implement this as things like IPersonService or IEmployeeService etc, with methods like `IEmployeeService.HireNewEmployee(args])`, or, if your domain is complex enough for this part of the system, a "Domain Model.

Whichever way you go, you'll find that these classes that implement the business logic will be invoked by the ViewModels.

Comment: Sigh. Downvote without a comment. Please let me know what I could do to improve the answer if you're going to say it's unhelpful.

Comment: Likely people who didn't understand MVVM, SOLID and DDD yet. Imho this is the correct answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

Model can and should contain business logic. ViewModel should NOT contain any business logic, just logic related to view.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular scenario, the logic can be added in View Model.

Remember the responsibilities-

Model - any logic which is a business logic and is a rule for that particular model or entity then that logic should be placed in Model.
for example - if you have an entity called as "Engine" the actual businesses of engine that is operational details how fast the gas gets pumped all that basic operations goes in Engine class which is model

View Model - any logic that is used for doing manipulations so as to show appropriate data on UI

Now how that engine should look whatever manipulations you need to do for managing UI, does not effects its working and is only related to UI hence those logic and details should go in View Model.

Answer (score -3):

Generally, validation is done at both ViewModels and Models. ViewModels tend to be mindful of the business-related logic, while Models' validation are used purely to make sure its data makes sense. For example, a `gender` property should be validated on `Person` Model. This is because this is a fact that gender can only be `male` or `female`, irregardless what the business logic is about.